# How to organize CSV data with unorganized array elements in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, ldap

I have this array that I want to output as a CSV file.

```
Array
(
    [dc=example,dc=com] => Array
        (
            [o] => example.com
            [objectclass] => Array
                (
                    [0] => simpleSecurityObject
                    [1] => dcObject
                    [2] => organization
                )

            [dc] => example
        )

    [uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com] => Array
        (
            [sn] => Newton
            [objectclass] => Array
                (
                    [0] => simpleSecurityObject
                    [1] => dcObject
                    [2] => organization
                )

            [uid] => Newton
            [mail] => newton@ldap.forumsys.com
            [cn] => Isaac Newton
        )

)
```

Currently, when I print all the data, this is what I get.

```
dn,o,objectclass,dc,sn, uid, mail, cn
dc=example,dc=com,example.com,simpleSecurityObject:dcObject:organization,example
uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com,Newton,simpleSecurityObject:dcObject:organization,Newton,newton@ldap.forumsys.com,Isaac Newton
```

This is just all the data printed in CSV format, but in the order they were arranged originally in the array.

I want to make sure all the elements actually match the values they're supposed to. Here's the output I want:

```
dn,o,objectclass,dc,sn, uid, mail, cn
dc=example,dc=com,example.com,{simpleSecurityObject,dcObject,organization},example, , , , 
uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com, ,{simpleSecurityObject,dcObject,organization},  ,Newton,Newton,newton@ldap.forumsys.com,Isaac Newton
```

Note that in the first element, we don't have sn, uid, mail, and cn attributes so those are left blank. The second element is missing o, and dc so those are blank.

Also the data is out of order as well currently.

How do I

1. make sure the data is in the right places
2. make sure any missing fields are left as "" rather than just skipping to the next element?

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$movies = array(
  
    "dc=example,dc=com" => array(
      "o" => "example.com", 
      "objectclass" => array("simpleSecurityObject", "dcObject", "organization"),
      "dc" => "example"),
    
  
    "uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com" => array(
      "sn" => "Newton", 
      "objectclass" => array("simpleSecurityObject", "dcObject", "organization"),
      "uid" => "Newton",
      "mail" => "newton@ldap.forumsys.com",
      "cn" => "Isaac Newton")
    
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($movies);
echo "</pre>";
function echo1($n){
  echo "<pre>";
  echo $n;
  echo "</pre>";
}
$i=0;
$single_val = "";

$attributes_list = array("dn", "objectclass", "cn", "userpassword", "description", "sn", "uid", "mail");

echo "<pre></pre>";
$comma_separated = implode(",", $attributes_list);
echo $comma_separated;


foreach ( $movies as $movie => $val ) {

    //echo "<pre></pre> \n Entry #$i";
    //This prints the name of all the arrays.
    //echo1($movie);
    echo "<pre></pre>";
    echo $movie.",";
    $i = $i + 1;

  //Checks if the value of the key value pair is an array.
  if(is_array($val)){
    //Since it's an array, we access its key value pairs again
    foreach ( $val as $key => $value ) {
      //Check to see if value of key value pair is array
      if(is_array($value)){
        //Prints the name of all the arrays
        //echo $key." ";
        //Prints all key value pairs of the array
        $value_array = implode(":", $value);
        $value_array = rtrim($value_array, ":");
        $value_array = $value_array.",";
        print_r($value_array);
        //If $value isn't an array, just prints the key value pairs
      } else{
          /*This is the original code for easier readability
          $hi = "$key : $value";
          echo1($hi);*/
          
          $lastElement = end($val);

          if($value != $lastElement){
            $single_val = $single_val.$value.",";
            echo $single_val;
            $single_val = "";
          } else{
            echo $value;
          }


        }
      }
    //If $val isn't an array, prints the key value pairs
  } else{
  foreach ( $val as $key => $value ) {
    $hi = "The key is: $key The value is:$value";
    echo1($hi);
    }
  }


}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
foreach ( $val as $key => $value ) {
```

With this

```
foreach ($attributes_list as $key){
    $value=$val[$key];
```

So you always print all the fields even if they are empty, and all stays in place.
If you don't want warning about missing key just check existence and print "" when it doesn't.

Then

```
$value_array = implode(":", $value);
$value_array = rtrim($value_array, ":");
$value_array = $value_array.",";
```

becomes

```
$value_array = implode(",", $value);
$value_array = "{".$value_array."},";
```

The `rtrim` should not be necessary. `Implode` puts strings inbetween values.